# Where can I see the anlytics from Google Anlytics SDK mobile implementations?

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics

I've added to my mobile projects the Google Analytics SDK for mobiles:

- [Android](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/)
- [iOS](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/)

Where can I see the analytics now ?

In my Google Analytics, I have the report in Public -> Mobile, but this data is for mobile devices visiting my web page, not for the mobile screens/activities use.

I can't find the place to see the native application mobile stats ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new PROFILE in the Google Analytics account.

Go to your account, click on Administrator, new profile, and select "MOBILE".

That will generate a new Profile (now in BETA) with the data collected from mobile SDK